# How to return two partial views in asp.net mvc?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

for example, in a Action, I get data and it will be shown in two different place, so I create two partial views, ViewA and ViewB. So the question is: how to return partial view ViewA and ViewB in the Action?

Comment: One Action Method can return only one View/Partial view.

Comment: Click this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937156/returning-multiple-partial-views-from-single-controller-action

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625002/how-to-insert-partial-views-dynamically-in-asp-net-mvc. But check the solution, with a custom extension of PartialViewResult, you can get your job done.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly ...

Firstly, you can't return multiple views from a action since there can't be multiple return from a method.
So to address your issue, create a model 'MODEL' with subclasses 'MODELA' and 'MODELB' in it catering the models for ViewA and ViewB. Create a view 'MainView', render the partial views ViewA and ViewB in 'MainView' using @Html.Partial.
While rendering viewA and viewB, pass @Model.MODELA and @Model.MODELB respectively.