# Add dynamically Partial view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, partial-views

I am newbie in ASP.NET MVC. I have a below requirement.

I need to show dynamically pie charts on the Dashboard page. I will decide total count of pie charts at run time. So, I have created a Partial View of the pie chart and a model class.

First, I will hit the database and fill data into model class. I din'd find any tutorial.

Controller Code :

```
public ActionResult _Dashboard()
    {
        try
        {
            _dashboard = new Dashboard();
            var model = _dashboard.GetToolsUtilization();
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        { }

    }
```

Tools class

```
public class Tools
{
    public string toolName { get; set; }
    public int used { get; set; }
    public int free { get; set; }
}
```

_Dashboard.cshtml Page

```
<div class="col-lg-12">



    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="dash-unit col-lg-3">
            Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/toolGaugeInfo.cshtml", item)
        </div>

    }

    </div>
```

ToolGauageInfo.cshtml

```
@model NETMS.DAL.ToolGauageInfo
```

I think, Partial view page is fine. I will call controller on page load by ajax call. Now, I don't know how to return model from controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Insert Partial views Dynamically in Asp.Net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625002/how-to-insert-partial-views-dynamically-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You will calculate number of pie charts and save it in a `List<PieChartModel>` or somrthing and you can create View that take `@model List<PieChartModel>` and loop over list to display your partialview

```
@foreach(var pie in Model)
{
   Html.Partial("_PieView", pie);
}
```

Comment: No, sorry. I tried but I wasn't able to achieve it.

Comment: @Mohit what do you mean by achieve it ?? What is the error ?

Comment: Share your code with more details including the partial view you implement and controller and your exact problem as now I don't understand you